# django-socialregistration error on loading button

Tags: python, django

With [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration), got following error:

```
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named httplib2
```

Error found in:

```
<form class="connect-button" name="login" method="post" action="{% url socialregistration:facebook:redirect %}">
```

How to get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).  Either:

```
pip install httplib2
```

or maybe on a debian-based system (ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
```